# Artin's Algebra: Homomorphism $S_4 \to S_3$

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation, symmetric-groups, group-homomorphism

I cannot understand Artin's example of a homomorphism from $S_4$ to $S_3$ in Examples 2.5.13.

He first partitions the indices $\{1,2,3,4\}$ into three pairs of two vertices:
$$ 
\Pi_1 = \{1,2\} \cup \{3,4\}, \; \Pi_2 = \{1,3\} \cup \{2,4\}, \; \Pi_3 = \{1,4\}, \{2,3\}.
$$
He argues that $\sigma \in S_4$, permuting the indices, also permutes the partitions, which makes sense to me. I can take some $\sigma \in S_4$, permute the indices individually, and then observe the effect on the partitions. Because it's a bijection, I'll make a partition into a partition. So the net effect of $p = (1234)$ is $(\Pi_1, \Pi_3)$, which I believe.

My problem is: how is this a homomorphism from $S_4$ to $S_3$? Is the idea to identify $S_4$ with an isomorphic group, these pairs of partitions, and then construct a homomorphism between $S_4$ and that group? I'm struggling to see exactly what the argument is.

Comment: To *each* $\sigma \in S_4$ you get a permutation $\pi_\sigma \in S_3$.  Strictly speaking $\pi_\sigma$ is in the group of permutations of $\{\Pi_1, \Pi_2, \Pi_3\}$, not $\{1,2,3\}$, as you already appear to realize.  It is not the specific effect on your $4$-cycle $p$ that is a homomorphism, but the effect on *all* elements of $S_4$ that is the homomorphism. The mapping $S_4 \to {\rm Sym}(\Pi_1,\Pi_2,\Pi_3)$ where $\sigma \mapsto \pi_\sigma$ for *all* $\sigma$ is a group homomorphism: check $\pi_{\sigma \circ \tau} = \pi_\sigma \circ \pi_\tau$ for all $\sigma$ and $\tau$ in $S_4$.

Comment: No you don't want to identify $S_4$ with an isomorphic group. You want to identify $S_3$ with the group ${\rm Sym}(X)$ of permutations of the set  $X = \{\Pi_1,\Pi_2,\Pi_3\}$. Now every element of $S_4$ induces a permutation of $X$ and that gives you your homomorphism $S_4 \to {\rm Sym}(X) \cong S_3$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $\sigma\in S_4$ and consider the $6$ sets $\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\{1,3\},\{2,4\},\{1,4\}$ and $\{2,3\}$. Then, since $\sigma$ is a bijection and these are the only subsets of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ with exactly $2$ elements, $\sigma$ maps $\{1,2\}$ into exactly one of these sets and it does the same thing with $\{3,4\}$. Furthermore, since $\sigma$ is a bijection, it maps $\{1,2\}$ and $\{3,4\}$ into two disjoint sets. But then one and only of of these possibilities takes place:

- $\sigma(\Pi_1)=\Pi_1$;
- $\sigma(\Pi_1)=\Pi_2$;
- $\sigma(\Pi_1)=\Pi_3$.

So, $\sigma$ acts as a permutation of the set $\{\Pi_1,\Pi_2,\Pi_3\}$. And this defines a group homomorphism from $S_4$ into $S_3$, since $S_3$ is the group of permutations of a set with $3$ elements.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather take $\Pi_1:=\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\}\}$, etc., and $X:=\{\Pi_i,i=1,2,3\}$. The map $S_4\times X\to X$, defined by:
$$\sigma\cdot\{\{i,j\},\{k,l\}\}:=\{\{\sigma(i),\sigma(j)\},\{\sigma(k),\sigma(l)\}\}$$
fulfils the axioms of a group action (because $\sigma$ is a bijection), and this action is equivalent to the homomorphism $\varphi\colon S_4\to S_X$ defined by:
$$\varphi_\sigma(\Pi_i):=\sigma\cdot\Pi_i$$
But $|X|=3$, and hence $S_X\cong S_3$.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative argument than book's one. A nontrivial homomorphism $\phi\colon S_4\to S_3$ is an $S_4$-action on the set $\{1,2,3\}$ with orbit equation $3=1+2$. Therefore, the kernel (which is the intersection of all the pointwise stabilzers) must be equal to $A_4$: all the even permutations of $S_4$ are sent to $()_{S_3}$, whereas all the odd ones (of order $2$ and $4$) must be sent to one same element of order $2$ (in a homomorphism, the order of the image of an element divides the order of the element). In particular, there are three nontrivial such homomorphisms, one for each element of order $2$ of $S_3$ (which are $(12)$, $(13)$ and $(23)$).

---

**Edit**. Also a transitive action is possibile, with the three stabilizers of order $8$ intersecting in the normal Klein four-(sub)group of $S_4$.