# Prove that the map from $S_4$ to $S_3$ is a homomorphism

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-homomorphism

In his *Algebra* Artin gives an example of a map from $S_4$ to $S_3$, which is realised by variously partitioning the former's set of four indices $\{1,2,3,4\}$ into pairs

$$\Pi_1:\{1,2\}\cup\{3,4\}, \;\Pi_2:\{1,3\}\cup\{2,4\},\; \Pi_3:\{1,4\}\cup\{2,3\}$$

and the set  $\{\Pi_1, \Pi_2, \Pi_3\}$ of order 3 is permuted along with $S_4$.

so far, so good, but the author then claims that it is a homomorphism. explaining that:

> If $p$ and $q$ are elements of $S_4$, the product $pq$ is the composed
> permutation $p \circ q$, and the action of $pq$ on the set $\{\Pi_1, \Pi_2, \Pi_3\}$is the composition of the actions of $q$ and $p$.
> Therefore $\varphi(pq) = \varphi(p)\varphi(q)$, and $\varphi$ is a
> homomorphism.

And yet I struggle to come up with a formal proof, only to end up with examples: take two elements from $S_4$, say (1234) and (24), then

$$\varphi((1234))=(\Pi_1\Pi_3), \varphi((24))=(\Pi_1\Pi_3)$$
$$\varphi((1234))\varphi((24))=(\Pi_1\Pi_3)(\Pi_1\Pi_3)=e$$

on the other hand:
$$(1234)(24)=(12)(34)$$
$$\varphi((1234)(24))=\varphi((12)(34))=e$$

hence
$$\varphi((1234))\varphi((24))=\varphi((1234)(24))$$

therefore $\varphi$ is etc.

which I find rather unsound. I'd like to know if Artin's intuitive proof could be made formal, thanks!

Comment: Welcome! Please do not rely on pictures of text. (They're not user friendly.)

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3365927/homomorphism-from-s-4-to-s-3?rq=1).

Comment: @Shaun oops, sorry for the inconvenience! I'll improve it right away.

Comment: You may want to check your notation. $\{1,2\}\cup \{3,4\} = \{1,3\}\cup \{2,4\} = \{1,4\}\cup \{2,3\} = \{1,2,3,4\}$.

Comment: @jjagmath I don't quite get your point, they are three ways of partitioning (into pairs of subsets of order 2), not three subsets. Anyway I did make to much omission, my apology.

Comment: That's precisely my point: $\{1,2\}\cup\{3,4\}$ is equal to the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$. It's not a partition of it. You want $\{\{1,2\}, \{3,4\}\}$

Comment: @jjagmath I see, I'll make a note of it, thank you! but since that's copied from Artin's book I'd rather let it remain that way for this post..

Comment: A [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4156080/artins-algebra-homomorphism-s-4-to-s-3?rq=1)?

Comment: @PeterMelech indeed, but the answer there addresses more permutation than homomorphism, what I can't figure out is how to produce a formal proof, something like $\varphi(a)\varphi(b)=\varphi(ab)$.

Comment: If you can prove that $S_4$ *acts* on $X:=\{\Pi_1,\Pi_2,\Pi_3\}$, then you automatically have a homomorphism from $S_4$ to $S_3$, since $|X|=3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, I'll rather take $\Pi_1:=\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\}\}$, etc., and $X:=\{\Pi_i,i=1,2,3\}$. The map $S_4\times X\to X$, defined by:
$$\sigma\cdot\{\{i,j\},\{k,l\}\}:=\{\{\sigma(i),\sigma(j)\},\{\sigma(k),\sigma(l)\}\}$$
fulfils the axioms of a group action, and this action is equivalent to the homomorphism $\varphi\colon S_4\to S_X$ defined by:
$$\varphi_\sigma(\Pi_i):=\sigma\cdot\Pi_i$$
But $|X|=3$, and hence $S_X\cong S_3$.

Comment: Thank you! since I haven’t learned about group actions so far it took me some time to catch up, but basically the proof via group action seems a paraphrase of Artin’s informal explanation, right? I mean that’s exactly what I am looking for, but just to check if I get you right, without mentioning any group actions, the proof goes more or less thus:

Comment: $\sigma_1\sigma_2\cdot\{\{i,j\},\{k,l\}\}=\{\{\sigma_1\sigma_2(i),\sigma_1\sigma_2(j)\},\{\sigma_1\sigma_2(k),\sigma_1\sigma_2(l)\}\}=\sigma_1\{\{\sigma_2(i),\sigma_2(j)\},\{\sigma_2(k),\sigma_2(l)\}\}$, is that correct? Nevertheless I have to admit it’s much clearer when identified  as a group action…

Comment: Better: $(\sigma_1\sigma_2)\cdot\{\{i,j\},\{k,l\}\}=\{\{\sigma_1\sigma_2(i),\sigma_1\sigma_2(j)\},\{\sigma_1\sigma_2(k),\sigma_1\sigma_2(l)\}\}=\sigma_1\{\{\sigma_2(i),\sigma_2(j)\},\{\sigma_2(k),\sigma_2(l)\}\}=\sigma_1\cdot(\sigma_2\cdot\{\{i,j\},\{k,l\}\})$

Comment: Yes, correct, @C_Arietta_C.

Comment: Nitpick, after the last but one "$=$", you'd write already "$\sigma_1\cdot$" etc..

Comment: Yes indeed! The operations within and without the curly braces should be distinguished.